# Means for calling back from Vulkan to host application

Tags: asynchronous, vulkan

Since Vulkan doesn't expose an async API, what are the alternatives for calling back from Vulkan to host application?

For example, let's say Vulkan is used to submit a single long-running compute task. How to notify the host once the task finishes without having to hold up a CPU thread on `vkQueueWaitIdle` or `vkWaitForFences`?

Comment: FYI: Vulkan doesn't work very well with long-running compute tasks. Most GPUs will kill tasks that take too long, which in Vulkan terms will cause your device to be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also query the Fence state (non-blockingly) with `vkGetFenceStatus()`.

If you want some other high-level construct like signal-slot or event message queue or even just a callback, you should be able to create it yourself from the provided Vulkan API.

Comment: It frankly sounds really simple to add something like that in the driver, though with plenty of bikeshedding oportunities. I once [suggested an extension to allow linking vkFences to kernel objects for use in epoll/WaitMultipleObjects](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/310) but it's been lying there without update...

Comment: @krOoze this seems to be the way to do it. I was also wondering if there's some driver level support for this perhaps or something similar to `vkDebugReportCallbackEXT`. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ratchetfreak Take a look at VK_KHX_external_semaphore_fd, which lets you export a fence_file (or the older staging/Android equivalent) fd from a VkSemaphore. You can then pass that to poll(2). Doing the same for VkFence is the obvious next step.

Comment: @JesseHall It says that the fd isn't compatible with anything other than dup dup2 close and dup3 (no epoll/select). There is a similar mechanism to export a vksemaphore to a D3D12 fence which in turn can be used to signal Event objects. It'd be nice if the Event object or fd could be tied directly to the Semaphore.

Comment: That's true for the OPAQUE_FD handle type, but not the FENCE_FD handle type.